# JavaScript and NodeJS: Calling method from different JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, methods

I am using NodeJS to include one js file into another. Below I show both my files. Both classes contain constructor for two objects. I would like to call a method in ClassB from ClassA. In ClassA, I require ClassB (as shown below) and I am trying to create a new instance of class B, and calling on it the method get of class B. I get the following error:

```
cB.get();
   ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/---/ClassA.js:12:4)
```

//ClassA.js

```
var imported = require('./ClassB');

function ClassA() 
{
    //....
}

var cA = new ClassA();
var cB = imported.ClassB();

cB.get();
```

//ClassB.js

```
function ClassB() 
{

    var myVar = 'test';

    function _get ()
    {
        return myVar;
    };

    this.get = function ()
    {
        return _get();
    };
 }

 exports.ClassB = ClassB;
```

I believe the problem is at how I instantiate the object of class B. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer

**ClassA**

```
var ClassB = require('./ClassB');
var cB = new ClassB("Test");
console.log(cB.get());
```

**ClassB:**

```
function ClassB(myVar){
  this.myvar = myVar;
};
ClassB.prototype.get = function(){
  return this.myvar;
};
module.exports = ClassB;
```

**CMD**

```
$ node ClassA.js 
Test
```

**ClassBV2**

```
function ClassB(){
  this.myvar = "Test";
};
```

**If you need _get to be private**

```
function ClassB(){
  this.myvar = "Test";
};
ClassB.prototype.get = function(){
  return _get();
};
_get = function(){
  return "Other";
}
module.exports = ClassB;
```

If you try to use it....

```
console.log(cB._get());
           ^
TypeError: Object #<ClassB> has no method '_get'
```

Comment: I need the _get function to be private and the get to be priviledged so I can not use prototype in this case

Comment: Ok updated to fit your need just for FYI keep using whatever way you want.

Comment: This way is cleaner. Accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `new` keyword when creating the instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate a constructor

```
function ClassB() 
{

    var myVar = 'test';

    function _get ()
    {
        return myVar;
    };

    this.get = function ()
    {
        return _get();
    };
 }

 exports.ClassB = new ClassB();
```

Comment: If I do that, how do I call the constructor from class A then?

Comment: Ok so I can do this: var cB = imported.ClassB;
 and looks allright

Comment: once you instantiate the new ClassB(), you should be able to utilize the exported ClassB.